# How can I extract the hour / minute from influxdb?

Tags: influxdb

I want to do some calculations with the hours and minutes of an InfluxDB record. I can get the timestamp and the formatted RFC 3339 date from a record, but not the individual parts such as an hour or minute. Is this possible with InfluxDB and how can I achieve this?

As a side note, I also record a date/time in string format that I could use theoretically, but I cannot find any database functions to transform / format that either.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to this has a feature request open in Flux project

[Support Calendar Time Operations](https://github.com/influxdata/flux/issues/426)